# Google core web vital latest release impact on ranking?

Tags: seo, core-web-vitals

Here is the recent timeline of keyword ranking of my site

```
On 12th May , my site was ranked number one on 1500 keywords
On 20th May , it ranked number one on 1900 keywords. Rank upgraded.
On 2nd June, it ranked number one on 800 keywords. Rank downgraded
```

Not sure what is happening here and how should I get RCA of it. Looks like google has started rolling out google core web vitals changes after 20th may , can it be because of that ?

Also are core web vitals changes are only related to site performance or other factors also like E-A-T/Content quantity and quality etc ?

Comment: I don't have data about what actually happened, but Google has been managing expectations that the ranking changes based on core vitals will be very small:  See [Google Says Pages With Core Web Vitals May Have Slight Ranking Advantage - Search Engine Roundtable](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-core-web-vitals-ranking-advantage-31071.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can find on Google docs and Twitter handle, Google is set to start including page experience signals in the ranking algorithm beginning mid-June.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/11/timing-for-page-experience

> We'll begin using page experience as part of our ranking systems
> beginning in mid-June 2021. However, page experience won't play its
> full role as part of those systems until the end of August. You can
> think of it as if you're adding a flavoring to a food you're
> preparing. Rather than add the flavor all at once into the mix, we'll
> be slowly adding it all over this time period.

However, there was a recent core update that got completed by May 18. Below is an update by one of the official handles of Google.

Ref: https://twitter.com/searchliaison/status/1257397733217968136

Based on the above two references, I am assuming that the core web vitals update is yet to start. Even if the update starts, the effects are going to be felt gradually.

Comment: Does recent core web vitals changes are only related to site  three vitals (CLS/LCP/FID )or other factors also like E-A-T/Content quantity and quality etc ? Also you said ` Google is set to start including page experience signals in the ranking algorithm beginning mid-June` I believe google earlier also using some performance/experience signals(i believe 6 web vitals CLS/LCP/FCP/SI/TTI/TBT ) in ranking but now it has define core vitals out of them and  changed their weightage ?

Comment: There has been a core update quite recently on June 2 as well - https://twitter.com/searchliaison.  These updates happen multiple times a year and are often are related to content quality/authority signals. From what I understand, page experience update is going to be a gradual one starting mid-June and culminating in August. Regarding signals, I am not entirely sure of the weightage changes if any. But I certainly believe that the three signals CLS/LCP/FID are very important from Google's pov today...

Comment: Moreover, many signals are related, For example, FID depends upon TTI and TBT. If you want to optimize for FID you want to optimize for TTI and TBT as well. And I believe the three signals are important in a real-world scenario. For example, FID can't be measured without users interacting with a web page.

Comment: The above observations are my understanding based on the limited information from official sources. I don't hesitate in saying I may be wrong by varying degrees in some way or the other. And I would certainly appreciate if someone corrects me if I missed something.